# .NET Core 3 with React - How to open new tab to display document

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to implement reporting in a  .NET Core 3.0 React application.
I'm using SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) for reporting.
I would like to have a report open in a new browser tab based open a selection value.

Here is the javascript:

```
if ($('.ddDisposition option:selected').text() == 'Print') {
    if (this.state.printUrl) {
       window.open(this.state.printUrl, _blank);
    }
}
```

I have tried the following url values for this.state.printUrl:

> /Report/DispositionPrint?id=ad2c916e-3a87-4697-81e4-768b58205f4d
>   /Report/DispositionPrint/ad2c916e-3a87-4697-81e4-768b58205f4d

The controller method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost("{id}")]  //Also tried [HttpGet]
[Route("DispositionPrint")]
public IActionResult DispositionPrint(Guid id)
{
    string url = ssrsUrl + @"?/Project/DispositionPrint&Id=" + id.ToString() + 
                 "&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Uri.EscapeUriString(url)); ;
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Credentials = nwc;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var contenttype = response.Headers["Content-Type"];
    return File(response.GetResponseStream(), contenttype);
}
```

I'm not concerned about the controller logic, this works fine.  However, i can't figure out how to get the react front-end to get to this method.
Currently, a new tab is opening but the DispositionPrint method is never being executed.

Neither state.printUrl noted above gets to the DispositionPrint method.Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem should be that the wrong url format was passed. And `Controller.File()` works with `[HttpGet]` , you should change HTTP method type from `[HttpPost]` to `[HttpGet]`.

1.If your controller routing configuration like below:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{id}")] 
    [Route("DispositionPrint")]
    public IActionResult DispositionPrint(Guid id)
    {
    }
```

use this.state.printUrl as `Test/DispositionPrint`  or `Test/ad2c916e-3a87-4697-81e4-768b58205f4d`.

2.If you pass `/Test/DispositionPrint/ad2c916e-3a87-4697-81e4-768b58205f4d` for this.state.printUrl , you should change the routing design as shown:

```
[HttpGet] 
[Route("DispositionPrint/{id}")]
public IActionResult DispositionPrint(Guid id)
{}
```

Reference : [Combining attribute routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#combining-attribute-routes)